# Why can't Docker container assign a requested address [::1]:50051?

Tags: linux, docker, rust, debian, grpc

I am trying to run a Rust-based gRPC app in a Docker container. When I run the command:

```
cargo run --bin helloworld-server
```

I get the error:

`Error: tonic::transport::Error(Transport, hyper::Error(Listen, Os { code: 99, kind: AddrNotAvailable, message: "Cannot assign requested address" }))`

I tried checking whether that address is in use, using the command `netstat`:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 52a52e6f2fd9:58140      151.101.22.132:http     TIME_WAIT
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

I don't see the address being used.

My `src/server.rs` file:

```
use tonic::{transport::Server, Request, Response, Status};

use hello_world::greeter_server::{Greeter, GreeterServer};
use hello_world::{HelloReply, HelloRequest};

pub mod hello_world {
    tonic::include_proto!("helloworld");
}

#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct MyGreeter {}

#[tonic::async_trait]
impl Greeter for MyGreeter {
    async fn say_hello(
        &self,
        request: Request<HelloRequest>,
    ) -> Result<Response<HelloReply>, Status> {
        println!("Got a request: {:?}", request);

        let reply = hello_world::HelloReply {
            message: format!("Hello {}!", request.into_inner().name).into(),
        };

        Ok(Response::new(reply))
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "[::1]:50051".parse()?;
    let greeter = MyGreeter::default();

    Server::builder()
        .add_service(GreeterServer::new(greeter))
        .serve(addr)
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.69.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y protobuf-compiler
WORKDIR /helloworld-tonic
COPY . ./helloworld-tonic/
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

Comment: What arguments did you specify when running `netstat`? Please try `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`.

Comment: For `[::1]`, is it actually trying to listen on an IPv6 port, and did you configure IPv6 support in Docker?

Comment: Note that the `netstat` output you gave says "w/o servers", which means it's not showing listening servers. You need to add the `-l` option to see listening sockets.